# Poison that disappears after it kills

Tags: medical, poisons

**Is it possible to have a poison that disappears from the corpse?**
I mean, you put the poison in the target, it kills the human and some minutes later the poison disappears from the corpse so any doctor is unable to find the poison.
Is such a poison possible and if so, what such poisons actually exist?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than making the poison disappear you want to disguise the death so that poison is never suspected in the first place. You may want to watch the CIA [Heart Attack Gun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSEnurBApdM). It was discussed during a [congressional hearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Committee). An alleged gun that injects poison into the recipient and mimics the symptoms of a heart attack.  So unless a doctor specifically thinks it was a murder they will just assume it was a heart attack, and even if they suspect that is difficult to prove.